# How can I change the default icon brings OneSignal making a post from Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, json, api, xamarin.forms, onesignal

I have done a post method to consult the OneSignal API Rest, that when an order has been accepted a notification is sent to the user from the device that placed the order and this is the code line that does not work, and it worked without the `small_icon`, `large_icon` and `android_accent_color`

**CODE:**

```
    public static void PostNotification(string idPush)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(AppSettings.OneSignalApi) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Headers.Add("authorization", AppSettings.KeyPush);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{"
                                    + $"\"app_id\": \"{AppSettings.PushIDApp}\","
                                    + "\"small_icon\": \"ic_stat_onesignal_default\","
                                    + "\"large_icon\": \"ic_onesignal_large_icon_default\","
                                    + "\"android_accent_color\": \"FFba3870\","
                                    + "\"contents\": {\"en\": \"Pedido Aceptado\"},"
                                    + $"\"include_player_ids\": [\"{idPush}\"]" +
                                    "}");

        string responseContent = null;

        try
        {
            using (var writer = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                writer.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }

            using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
```

I have the icons but it does not show them, it does not send me the notification with it, just removing the following 3 properties, `small_icon`, `large_icon` and `android_accent_color` I do not know if the way I am doing it will be wrong, and I have followed the documentation of the [Create Notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification#create-notification).

Comment: When sending notifications with images (large images and icons), each device that receives the push needs to download that image. If the server cannot handle that bandwidth, you should try:  1.Decreasing the Image File size by lowering the quality and/or the image size to the recommended settings. 2.Scatter the notifications using our Intelligent Delivery or Timezone Settings or using Segments. You could google with the keyword as **Notification Images Not Showing** to check the related link.

Comment: @y3z1 I already have all the images of the icon in the size that each of them needs, in their respective folders, but what happens is that the notification is not sent if you put what is the small icon, large icon, and android accent color, I don't know if the reference is wrong, but the Android project in resources, I generate folders like hdpi, etc., but they are not with the initial word that is drawable, I am using Visual Studio 2019